# How to save/output data periodically in SIMULINK?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am new in SIMULINK!

I have a large SIMULINK model, possibly to be run for one-year simulation (time resolution is 1 second). So I need to save data periodically (let's say the total sum for every day). I tried to generate a custom Matlab function for that (the code given below).

For the code: I am having difficulty to write the data saved every 10 s to workspace or to mat file.

Any other approaches rather than this code are highly welcome.

Simulink Model: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtIKY.png)

The Code (sum_in and sum_out connected with the memory block & t is from the clock block)

```
function [y,sum_out] = fcn(t,sum_in)

t_duration=30;              % [s] Total duration of simulation

t_resol=10;                 % [s] Save every 10 s

sum_result=zeros(t_duration/t_resol,1);

t_per = mod(t,t_resol);

index=floor(t/t_resol)+1;

if t_per==1
    sum_result(index,1)=sum_out;
    save trial.mat sum_result;
    sum_in=0;
    sum_out=sum_in+1;
else
    sum_out=sum_in+1;
end

y=sum_out;
```

Comment: Is your goal to have the data available during simulation? My first idea would be to actually downsample in your Model, and then log the new Signal with the slower sample time.

Comment: Not necessarily to read the data during the simulation. What I want, when the simulation will be finalized, to read the final data saved every day (sum of the data by the simulation time step (1s).